# Unable to Start ResourceManager (capacity-scheduler.xml) not found hadoop 2-6.0

Tags: hadoop

I installed haddop-2.6.0 and followed the Single Cluster instructions from Apache Site http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html

When i tried to start ResourceManager using the following command

$ sbin/start-yarn.sh

I am getting no error in the console how ever when i see the resource manager log i am seeing the errors. here is the log

```
    2015-02-05 19:59:08,360 INFO  [main] resourcemanager.RMNMInfo (RMNMInfo.java:<init>(63)) - Registered RMNMInfo MBean
2015-02-05 19:59:08,360 INFO  [main] metrics.SystemMetricsPublisher (SystemMetricsPublisher.java:serviceInit(92)) - YARN system metrics publishing service is not enabled
2015-02-05 19:59:08,361 INFO  [main] util.HostsFileReader (HostsFileReader.java:refresh(129)) - Refreshing hosts (include/exclude) list
2015-02-05 19:59:08,364 INFO  [main] conf.Configuration (Configuration.java:getConfResourceAsInputStream(2231)) - capacity-scheduler.xml not found
2015-02-05 19:59:08,388 INFO  [main] service.AbstractService (AbstractService.java:noteFailure(272)) - Service org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler failed in state INITED; cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue configuration missing child queue names for root
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue configuration missing child queue names for root
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler.parseQueue(CapacityScheduler.java:558)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler.initializeQueues(CapacityScheduler.java:463)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler.initScheduler(CapacityScheduler.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler.serviceInit(CapacityScheduler.java:324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$RMActiveServices.serviceInit(ResourceManager.java:558)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.createAndInitActiveServices(ResourceManager.java:989)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.serviceInit(ResourceManager.java:255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.main(ResourceManager.java:1210)
2015-02-05 19:59:08,390 INFO  [main] service.AbstractService (AbstractService.java:noteFailure(272)) - Service RMActiveServices failed in state INITED; cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue configuration missing child queue names for root
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue configuration missing child queue names for root
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler.parseQueue(CapacityScheduler.java:558)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler.initializeQueues(CapacityScheduler.java:463)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler.initScheduler(CapacityScheduler.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler.serviceInit(CapacityScheduler.java:324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$RMActiveServices.serviceInit(ResourceManager.java:558)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.createAndInitActiveServices(ResourceManager.java:989)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.serviceInit(ResourceManager.java:255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.main(ResourceManager.java:1210)
2015-02-05 19:59:08,390 INFO  [main] impl.MetricsSystemImpl (MetricsSystemImpl.java:stop(210)) - Stopping ResourceManager metrics system...
2015-02-05 19:59:08,391 INFO  [main] impl.MetricsSystemImpl (MetricsSystemImpl.java:stop(216)) - ResourceManager metrics system stopped.
2015-02-05 19:59:08,391 INFO  [main] impl.MetricsSystemImpl (MetricsSystemImpl.java:shutdown(605)) - ResourceManager metrics system shutdown complete.
2015-02-05 19:59:08,391 INFO  [main] event.AsyncDispatcher (AsyncDispatcher.java:serviceStop(138)) - AsyncDispatcher is draining to stop, igonring any new events.
2015-02-05 19:59:08,391 INFO  [main] service.AbstractService (AbstractService.java:noteFailure(272)) - Service ResourceManager failed in state INITED; cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue configuration missing child queue names for root
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue configuration missing child queue names for root
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler.parseQueue(CapacityScheduler.java:558)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler.initializeQueues(CapacityScheduler.java:463)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler.initScheduler(CapacityScheduler.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler.serviceInit(CapacityScheduler.java:324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$RMActiveServices.serviceInit(ResourceManager.java:558)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.createAndInitActiveServices(ResourceManager.java:989)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.serviceInit(ResourceManager.java:255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.main(ResourceManager.java:1210)
2015-02-05 19:59:08,392 INFO  [main] resourcemanager.ResourceManager (ResourceManager.java:transitionToStandby(1058)) - Transitioning to standby state
2015-02-05 19:59:08,392 INFO  [main] resourcemanager.ResourceManager (ResourceManager.java:transitionToStandby(1068)) - Transitioned to standby state
2015-02-05 19:59:08,392 FATAL [main] resourcemanager.ResourceManager (ResourceManager.java:main(1214)) - Error starting ResourceManager
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue configuration missing child queue names for root
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler.parseQueue(CapacityScheduler.java:558)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler.initializeQueues(CapacityScheduler.java:463)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler.initScheduler(CapacityScheduler.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler.serviceInit(CapacityScheduler.java:324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$RMActiveServices.serviceInit(ResourceManager.java:558)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.createAndInitActiveServices(ResourceManager.java:989)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.serviceInit(ResourceManager.java:255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.main(ResourceManager.java:1210)
2015-02-05 19:59:08,403 INFO  [Thread-1] resourcemanager.ResourceManager (StringUtils.java:run(659)) - SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

I have the file capacity-scheduler.xml in hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop/ folder

Not sure what went wrong.

I am able to start the namenode using start-dfs without any issues.

jps show the following

```
9379 SecondaryNameNode
9057 NameNode
9199 DataNode
12861 Jps
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the capacity-scheduler.xml in your config directory or in your classpath. You can pull a default example copy of it from [here](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-tests/src/test/resources/capacity-scheduler.xml)